# Append virtual static column/field in Laravel query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I have two scenarios to implement in my query from the same database table and show them in two different front-end tables. The problem is I need to implement both of the scenarios in a single query maybe with `union`. 
I want to know if the current result belongs to `scenario 1` or `scenario 2`. For that purpose, I want to add a virtual column in my query like `scenario 1` or the `scenario 2` to identify the results. Is it possible with laravel eloquent or `raw` query?

```
$a = orderModel::virtualColumn('scenario-1')

$b = orderModel::virtualColumn('scenario-2')
->union($a)
->get();

$result = $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Virtual Columns in Laravel - Accessors and Appends

```
class Order extends Model
{
    $appends = [
        'scenario'
    ];

    public function getScenarioAttribute()
    {
        return $this->fields_one . " " . $this->fields_two;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it will work. It will call this attribute in both of the scenarios in the same way.

Comment: I want to get the `scenario-1` and `scenario-2` strings in both scenarios respectively